# Grails - Can I use maven repo(.m2) path as ivy-cache path

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I find some document [Grails 2.1.1](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/guide/introduction.html), it says we can customize ivy-cache folder.

I have a doubt, can I specify my Maven repo (.m2) path as ivy-cache path?

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    cacheDir "target/ivy-cache"
}
```

You can change the ivy cache directory for all projects via settings.groovy

```
grails.dependency.cache.dir = "${userHome}/.ivy2/cache"
```

Does this work? Does it support all scenarios? Is it giving any better performance than ivy-cache?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

In Grails 2.3, [it seems like we'll be able to forget about ivy](http://grails.io/post/40093552028/road-to-grails-2-3-improved-dependency-resolution)... :-).

Then in the BuildConfig.groovy, we'll be able to specify this :

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

---

No, the folder structures and metadata are different.

```
com.foo.something vs com/foo/something
```

See the answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520801/grails-how-to-make-grails-get-latest-local-jars-from-maven-repository) about forcing the ivy-cache refresh.

Comment: you are absolutely right, but is there any way to make into single formate