# Grails - How to make ivy-cache folder structure the same as maven repository folder structure?

Tags: grails, ivy, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Is it possible to make ivy-cache folder structure the same as maven's repository folder structure?
I am planning to use the same location (path,folder) as maven repository and ivy-cache.

I'm getting some dependency issues. To resolve them, I feel this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Witch dependencies issues you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520801/grails-how-to-make-grails-get-latest-local-jars-from-maven-repository